# Deformations of CFTs

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory, wess-zumino-witten

Do you know of any textbooks/lecture notes that treat marginal and or relevant deformations of CFT's / WZW-models?

Answer (score 1):

For deformations of boundary CFT and boundary WZW models, see Chapter 5 of the book "Boundary Conformal Field Theory and the Worldsheet Approach to D-Branes", by Recknagel and Schomerus.